# How can you install third-party libraries such as numpy/scipy into the Windows Python embeddable zip file?

Tags: python, numpy, deployment, scipy

I am trying to install numpy/scipy/pandas/scikit-learn into the windows zip file python version that can be found on the  main website:

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-361/: 
"Windows x86-64 embeddable zip file"

I want to create a portable python version with all libraries I need installed which I can be copy for easy deployment onto customer computers. Could someone please outline the process to install the libraries mentioned?

(The overall idea is I have a C# app that requires some embedded python scripts to run, thus need python environment on the customer's computer and easy way to deploy it. If there are better methods than mentioned above currently being used for commercial deployment, please let me know.)

Thank you in advance for any help, appreciate it.